# system.net.mail.attachments add error "Sorry something went wrong... "

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm using VB.NET and creating a new Mail outlook item using Microsoft.Interop.Outlook ver#15.

I can create an Email object and set the Subject, Body, ToAddress, ccAddress, etc. just fine and display the new Email.

I am having issues when I try and add a .pdf file via file path string to Attachments using the .Add method. Get an error "Sorry something went wrong.. " I have moved the file into different folders locally and same error.

```
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)

mailItem.Subject = _sSubject
mailItem.To = sToAddress
mailItem.CC = sCCAddress
mailItem.Body = sBody

''Commented out for now Until I can figure out error!! 
For Each _File As String In sAttachList
    Dim _AttachObject As New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(_File)

    mailItem.Attachments.Add(_AttachObject)

Next

mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal
mailItem.Display(True)
mailItem = Nothing
oApp = Nothing
```

Comment: What is the actual value of _File, how is sAttachList constructed?  and at exactly what point do you get that error?

Comment: _File is actually the full path string to the location of the PDF File "C:\Temp\POReport_126.pdf"

Comment: The error is when the mailItem.Attachments.Add is called with that new Mail.Attachment.

Comment: Next question then, how is the attachment file constructed? Guessing being in the temp folder, you're generating this file further up your code, are you sure the file processing is complete and all handles to that file are released etc when it hits the error?  My experience is there is always a bit of a delay between completing writing a file before I can access it again

Comment: That `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` class has nothing to do with Outlook. That is for when you create your own `MailMessage` and send it using an `SmtpClient`. Outlook Automation has all its own types. I suspect that, if you had `Option Strict On`, that code wouldn't even compile because a specific type is expected there.

Comment: Thanks I think that might be the issue right there, just not the right class for attaching an object to an Outlook email. Yes the File is released.. I tested with many different files not just the one I'm creating via ReportVIewer to PDF. Thanks All I am going to try these options out today. So appreciate the assistance!!

Comment: Thanks that was the resolution! Just needed to pass the FilePath string right to the mailItem.Attachments.Add.. so it was using the wrong class object.. system.net.mail. Thanks much! Turning option strict on!

Answer (score 0):

I think, this line is the problem:

```
Dim _AttachObject As New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(_File)
```

Why not just add the absolute file paths? So this one should do it:

```
For Each _File As String In sAttachList
    mailItem.Attachments.Add(_File)
Next
```

I use this functions:

```
Private Function Correct(Value As String) As String
    If Value = "" Then Return Value
    Return Value.Trim.Replace(",", ";").Replace(" ", "")
End Function

Private Sub AddAttachments(ByRef Mail As Outlook.MailItem, Attachments As String())
    If Attachments Is Nothing OrElse Attachments.Count = 0 Then Return

    For Each Attachment As String In Attachments
        Mail.Attachments.Add(Attachment)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub SendMail(Receiver As String,
                    Subject As String,
                    Body As String,
                    Optional CC As String = "",
                    Optional BCC As String = "",
                    Optional Attachments As String() = Nothing)

    Receiver = Correct(Receiver)
    If Receiver = "" Then Return

    Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem = CType(OUT.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)
    With Mail
        .To = Receiver
        .Subject = Subject.Trim
        .Body = Body.Trim
        .CC = Correct(CC)
        .BCC = Correct(BCC)

        AddAttachments(Mail, Attachments)

        If MyAccount IsNot Nothing Then .SendUsingAccount = MyAccount

        If MySentFolder IsNot Nothing Then .SaveSentMessageFolder = MySentFolder

        .Send()
    End With

    Mail = Nothing
End Sub
```

These are functions in a Outlook class, so some objects need explanation:

- OUT is an openend Outlook.Application object
- MyAccount is an Outlook.Account object. You can use it to send the mail with another account than the default
- MySentFolder is an Outlook.Folder object. You can use it, if you want to store the sent mail in another folder than the default sent folder.

Surely you can omit these two lines in the code.

Comment: Thanks much Aranxo I will try those changes. Sure appreciate the help on this!